# How to write a file from iOS8 share extension that host app can read?

Tags: ios, ios8, ios8-extension, ios8-share-extension

I have a share extension in iOS8 that I'm invoking from Safari. After it runs it has some data that it wants to share with the main application (for which both are using a shared app group), however the data is far too big to stuff into the user settings, it needs to be stored as a file. How do I write the file such that when my main app is loaded it can see the file?

For clarity, I'm not talking about downloading a remote file, the file is created in memory by the share extension.

EDIT: Spelling correction.